# Calculating areal distribution of soil types within catchment layer in QGIS

Tags: qgis, field-calculator, area, catchment-area, soil

I have two polygons:

- Layer with +100 river catchments
- Soil type layer (8 different soil types)

I want to calculate the areal distribution of soil types within each river catchment. Areas should preferably be added to the catchment layer as separate columns for each soil type for further processing.

Comment: Are you asking how to `interect` data and then calculate the  `$area` of each intersected polygon?

Comment: `intersect` would be the correct tool.